# NodeJs - Access variable which is inside a function

Tags: node.js, variables, global-variables, url-shortener

So essentially I am using the **node-url-shortener** library to shorten a link, however, after using that function I want to pass the new shortened link (shortenedUrl) outside of the function and then log it in the console.

If I throw the console.log inside the function it logs perfectly fine but obviously that is not what I'm trying to achieve here...

This was my attempt at doing so:

```
const shortUrl = require('node-url-shortener');

var shortenedUrl;

shortUrl.short('www.google.com', function(err, shortUrl){
  shortenedUrl = shortUrl;
  // do somemthing here to pass the shortenedUrl outside the function
});

console.log(shortenedUrl);
```

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: no you have to put your logic inside, this is called *"callback"*. outside code runs sequentially, when .short finishes, it calls your _callback_

Comment: Use promise or call back function concept over here. Above code execution in sequence way, so that you will get "undefined" as a output in console.

Comment: @EricWong could you please explain how & where to implement a callback in my script above?